# Designing physics bodies other than circles

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I'm making my first game with SpriteKit and for the enemy aliens (SKSpriteNode subclass) physics bodies I have been using:

`self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: self.size.width/2)`

this has worked so far as most of the aliens are circle-shaped. However, if I were to have ellipse or square aliens what would be the best method of designing their physics bodies? I tried this for square shape:

```
let squarePath = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: -64, y: -64, width: 128, height: 128))
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: squarePath.CGPath)
```

but I don't know if this is the most efficient, and also don't know how to exactly make ellipses. Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using paths is the only way to create complex physics bodys, however, you can create rectangles with SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))

Edit:
Use this to help create efficient paths from images: http://insyncapp.net/SKPhysicsBodyPathGenerator.html

Note: this will only generate the paths for the image, you will need to clean it up your self by deleting paths and connecting the points.

Comment: Are ovals considered complex? And how do they impact performance?

Comment: Yes ovals are considered complex. Circles are the least complex because its a simple distance equation from the center point. If you need more complex physics bodies, create them from UIbezier paths but try to limit how many points there are in the final path. So you could do an oval without much performance cost if you used only 8 straight lines to create the oval-ish path.

Comment: I added something that may help you create good paths for your images. You can clean up the paths generated here: http://insyncapp.net/SKPhysicsBodyPathGenerator.html for your images and get nice results.

Answer (score 2):

### Let SpriteKit draw the shape for you!

If you have a sprite and you need to create a `PhysicsBody` for it just let SpriteKit do it for you. SpriteKit can analyze the texture, find the borders (using the alpha/transparent channel) and finally create a physics body matching the image.

Let's say I add this sprite to my scene

```
let croc = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "croc_walk01")
croc.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
addChild(croc)
```

[image]

### Automatically creating a PhysicsBody shape

Now I simply add this line

```
croc.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: croc.texture!, size: croc.texture!.size())
```

And SpriteKit automatically creates the PhysicsBody for me.

[image]

Can you see the line line around the sprite? That's it. Let me hide the sprite so you can see it better

```
croc.hidden = true
```

[image]

Comment: This works but it is inefficient so is not the best if you can settle for a much less resource intensive circle or simple polygon.

Comment: AppzYourLife @StephenKac is there a way to specify points? Or would this seek an efficient configuration if my shape was relatively simple- like an oval?

Comment: This way would seek an efficient configuration if it was a square. But an oval is by no means efficient. It requires many more calculations than a circle would. I would use this method on very specific characters but no more than 2 or three. And yes there is a way to specify points by using Custom UI bezier paths.

Comment: @StephenKac I think what Sam is asking, about points, is that most vector tracing apps provide a setting that specifies the complexity (number of) points used to trace any given shape. Is there something like this setting for tracing images into Sprite Kit physics bodies so they don't wind up with dozens (or hundreds) of vertices?

Comment: You do not have such fine grain control over sprite kits method to create a physics body. I thought there was a way to make even more accurate physics bodies than the above method but Currently cannot find that either in the Docs.